# Can we retrieve files stored on a computer with google script? If yes, how?

Tags: google-apps-script

I use google apps script for work. I would like to know if it is possible to recover and read a file from my pc ? 
I can recover my different files stored on the google drive with the class "file", but I don't know if we can recover files stored on a pc...

I searched carefully the documentation of google on the net, but I did not find anything about it.

Thanks you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

### If you are searching for a solution to retrieve files stored on a computer without uploading them on Google Drive, you can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader).

Example:

> HTML file

```
  <body>
  Upload file: <input type="file" id="p">
  <input type="button" onClick="fileSubmit()" value="Confirm"><br>
  <script>
   function fileSubmit(){
       var file    = document.getElementById("p").files[0]; 
       var reader  = new FileReader();
       if (file) {
           //reads the data as a URL
           reader.readAsDataURL(file); 
           reader.onloadend = function () {
           google.script.run.doSomething(reader.result);
          }           
       }                      
  }
  </script>
  </body>
```

> Script file

```
function doGet(){
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}    
function doSomething(file) {
  // do something with the file retrieved from the computer as a DataURL
}
```

You need to deploy your project as a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#deploying_a_script_as_a_web_app) in order to implement this solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access them, if you upload them to your drive. Or directly access them from the HtmlService/sidebar/web apps:

```html
<input type="file" name="myFile">
```

And then handle them client side in the browser or pass it server side, where they become blob objects.

#### References:

- [Web App § Forms § File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication#forms)
- [Using files from web apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications)